# My website uses multiple pop-ups, some contain videos. The first video replaces all other videos. I am using html, css and javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, video, responsive-design

## Video in first pop-up overrules all other videos in other pop-ups.

I hope you guys can help me with this problem. It seems the first pop-up and its code is overriding all the other pop-ups and is therefor replacing all the videos.

Below is the html for one pop-up, it is the same on all other pop-ups:

```
<!-- link on homepage -->
<div class="pure-u-1-2">
    <br>
    <div class="blackbg image">
        <h2>If I Remember Correctly...</h2>
        <a href="#21-ifiremembercorrectly"><img src="images/home-
        ifiremembercorrectly.png"></a>
    </div><br>
</div>
<!-- Pop-up -->
<div id="21-ifiremembercorrectly" class="modalDialog pure-g">
    <div>
        <a href="#close" title="Close" class="close">&times;</a>
        <div id="scrollable01">
            <h1>If I Remember Correctly... (2017)</h1>
            <p><i>title</i><br><br> text
                <br><br></p>
            <div class="videocontainer"><iframe id="vi-ifiremembercorrectly" class="video" width="960" height="540" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/IsdtZ46oPbc?
         rel=0&amp;controls=0&amp;showinfo=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen>
         </iframe></div><br><br>
            <img src="images/home-ifiremembercorrectly_black.png"><br><br>
            <img src="images/ifiremembercorrectly-02.png"><br><br>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And this is the css for the pop-up:

```
.modalDialog {
    position: fixed;
    font-family: 'GT Cinetype Trial Light', Helvetica;
    font-size: 15px;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,1);
    z-index: 99999;
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 200ms ease-in;
    -moz-transition: opacity 200ms ease-in;
    transition: opacity 200ms ease-in;
    pointer-events: none;
    color: white;
    letter-spacing: 0px;
}

.modalDialog:target {
    opacity:1;
    pointer-events: auto;
}

.modalDialog > div {
    width: 50%;
    height: 80%;
    position: relative;
    margin: 10% auto;
    padding: 5px 20px 13px 20px;
    background: black;
}

p {
    max-width: 480px;
}

.close {
    background: black;
    color: white;
    line-height: 25px;
    position: absolute;
    right: -6px;
    text-align: center;
    top: -5px;
    width: 24px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 25px;
}

.close:hover {
    background: #000;
}

#scrollable01 {
    height: 100%;
    overflow: scroll;
}
```

Last of all, here is a link to the website. This might help the most I guess:
http://www.jurritvanderploeg.nl/

Thanks in advance! Hope everything is clear what I am asking help for.

Answer (score 0):

it could be caused by the CSS

```
.modalDialog {
    position: fixed;
    font-family: 'GT Cinetype Trial Light', Helvetica;
    font-size: 15px;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,1);
    z-index: 99999;
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 200ms ease-in;
    -moz-transition: opacity 200ms ease-in;
    transition: opacity 200ms ease-in;
    pointer-events: none;
    color: white;
    letter-spacing: 0px;
}
```

you set the background to black, so it overides all the videos on the background if you change the background color to transparent or remove it it should work, and it will show all the videos on the back

Comment: I can't really see something you changed here. If I get your comment correctly, I tried it and it didn't work. I came to the conclusion that all videos are on display:block, so I tried and work something out with putting all videos on display:none and use display:block when clicking on an image. But this had no results, I think the pop-up is interfering. Any thoughts about it?